# How to generate UsernameToken for SOAP request?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wss4j, usernametoken

I want to generate "UsernameToken-28FE7B32CCC1AB2B22141113557641136"> in Java in order to send a request to a SOAP web service. Using SoapUI and the request is easy, because it will autogenerate, but how can i do this in java? I am currently sending the request from an external file, how can i do this from Java and autogenerate the UsernameToken?

Here is my code:

```
public class SampleHttpClient
{
  public static String invokeWebService(String webServiceURL,
String  requestXMLPath)
throws FileNotFoundException, Exception
{
PostMethod post = null;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

try
{
  // Read the SOAP request from the file
  StringBuffer requestFileContents = new StringBuffer();
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(requestXMLPath));
  String line = null;

  while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
  {
    requestFileContents.append(line);
  }

  post = new PostMethod(webServiceURL);
  post.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/soap+xml,application/dime,multipart/related,text/*");
  post.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "");

  // Request content will be retrieved directly from the input stream
  RequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(requestFileContents.toString(), "text/xml",  "UTF-8");

  post.setRequestEntity(entity);


  // Returns a number indicating the status of response
  int result = client.executeMethod(post);
  String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
  //bufferedReader.close();
  return response;
}

finally
{
  // Release current connection to the connection pool once you are done
  post.releaseConnection();

}
}
}
```

And the invokeWS code:

```
public class SampleTest extends TestCase
{
 public void test() throws FileNotFoundException, Exception
 {
   // Web service URL #1
   final String wsURL = "http://webservice";


   // Request XML path
   final String requestXMLPath = "C:\\request.txt";



   //Invoke the Web service #1
   String webServiceResponse = SampleHttpClient.invokeWebService(wsURL,requestXMLPath);
   System.out.println("Response #1: " + webServiceResponse);

 }
}
```

Here is the XML request(modified for security issues):

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://webservice">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-28FC7B32CCC1BB2B21141113657641136"><wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">password=</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">gt/swtwet/ww==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2014-09-19T14:22:56.411Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:getThis1>
         <v2:getThis12>
            <v3:getThis13>
               <v3:getThis10>
                  <v31:Id>31045243</v31:Id>
                  <v31:getThis1222>545345</v31:getThis1222>
               </v3:getThis10>
               <v3:Number>1234124</v3:Number>
            </v3:getThis14323>
         </v2:getThis1343>
      </v2:getThis112>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: There are some info in this post. See if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435580/add-wsseusernametoken-in-soap-header

Answer (score 3):

As in [Add wsse:UsernameToken in soap header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435580/add-wsseusernametoken-in-soap-header)

You can add a UsernameToken to the message this way:

```
//create SOAP
        SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement Header = soapBody.addBodyElement(new QName("Header"));

//attribute                     
        SOAPElement Security= Header.addChildElement(new QName("Security"));
        SOAPElement UsernameToken= Security.addChildElement(new QName("UsernameToken"));
        SOAPElement Username= UsernameToken.addChildElement(new QName("Username"));
        SOAPElement Password= UsernameToken.addChildElement(new QName("Password"));

//enter the username and password
Username.addTextNode("username");
Password.addTextNode("password");

//send the soap and print out the result
URL endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/soap/getMessage?wsdl";
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(soapMessage, endpoint);
```

---

**EDITED**

If you already have the message in a string, you should first create the `SoapMessage` object, from your `string`.

Use the method below:

```
private SOAPMessage getSoapMessageFromString(String xml) throws SOAPException, IOException {
    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    return message;
}
```

Comment: thanks, so with that, should i remove the line from my request where i send the token,username&password? and your code will add the token,user&pass to the request?

Comment: If you already have the message in a string, you should first create the SoapMessage from the string, then alter the properties you want. I added some info.